# How to get the count of numbers like and reached in iOS iPhone Couchbase?

Tags: ios, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-view

How does it work in iOS? Currently using Objective C.

Created in Document.

```
LIKE
{
  "_id": "",
  "userEmail": "",
  "broadcastID": "",
  "like": "",
  "count": 0,
  "type": "like"
}
```

and

```
REACH
{
  "_id": "",
  "userEmai": "",
  "broadcastID": "",
  "reach": "",
  "count": 0,
  "type": "reach"
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Count Numbers of Likes/Reached

[image]

Comment: In this you have get response as array ?

Answer (score 0):

A typical approach would be to create a view with a map function that emits (places into the index) the values you care about.  You can then run queries based on the view to further refine the information you retrieve.

Between the map function and query options, you have a lot of control over the information you retrieve.  For example, you already have a 'type' field, so it's easy to have your map function only produce output for documents of the correct type.